# MySQL: Query userid if contains such as actions

Tags: mysql

Here is a sample table:

```
userid, action

123, play
123, purchase,
345, login
123, level_up
456, sign_out
```

How would I query userid's that have action = 'play' and action = 'level_up'?

I want it to print something like

```
123, play
123, purchase, 
123, level_up
```

This is my closes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid
FROM sampleTable
WHERE action IN ('purchase', 'level_up')
```

Comment: your question "How would I query userid's that have action = 'play'?" and what you want is not matching

Comment: ambiguous question !!, clarify your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM SampleTable
WHERE userid IN
    (SELECT userid
     FROM SampleTable
     WHERE action='play')
ORDER BY userid, action;
```

Comment: Change the where clause on the inner select: `where action in ('play','level_up')`

Comment: I may have misinterpreted what you meant. The query in my answer looks for any userid that has a 'play' action, it then prints out all actions for those userids. So it gives the same output as the sample in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from sampleTable where id = (select id from sampleTable where action = 'play' )
```

selecting the id of the action with value "play: first would do the trick

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id = (select id from sampletable where action = 'play')' at line 1

Comment: deleted the "action" text typo

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userid,action
FROM sampleTable
WHERE action IN ('play', 'level_up')
```

Simply it should work.

For purchase action -

```
SELECT userid,action
FROM sampleTable
WHERE action IN ('play', 'level_up', 'purchase')
```

Comment: this won't select the 'purchase' action

Comment: How would I query userid's that have action = 'play' and action = 'level_up'? This is the question.

Comment: you should look at the sample output the OP wants

Comment: i had edited my answer considering both question and output

Answer (score 0):

I misinterpreted the question, but now that I have re-read it I think this is closer to the mark...

```
SELECT t.userid, t.action, t2.action
FROM SampleTable t
JOIN SampleTable t2 ON t.userid=t2.userid
WHERE t.action='play' AND t2.action='level_up'
ORDER BY t.userid;
```

This will show userids that have both an action of 'play' and an action of 'level_up'.